# Haskell main function

Tags: haskell

```
module Main where

qsort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
qsort [] = []
qsort (x : xs) = qsort smaller ++ [x] ++ qsort larger
                 where
                   smaller = [a | a <- xs , a <= x]
                   larger  = [a | a <- xs , a >  x]

main = do qsort [1,3,2]
```

I get the following error

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO t0' with actual type `[a0]'         
In the expression: main
When checking the type of the function `main'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

All functions within a `do` block must match the monadic value being returned.  You could instead write

```
main = do
    print (qsort [1, 3, 2])
```

Because `print` returns an `IO` value.  Similarly, if you were using the `Maybe` monad, you would have to do something like

```
-- lookup :: Eq k => k -> [(k, v)] -> Maybe v
-- listToMaybe :: [a] -> Maybe a

firstElementOf :: Eq q => k -> [(k, [v])] -> Maybe v
firstElementOf key assocMap = do
    v <- lookup key assocMap
    first <- listToMaybe v
    return first
```

This works because `lookup` and `listToMaybe` both return a `Maybe`, which is the return value of the overall `do` block as specified by the type signature of `firstElementOf`.

Looking at the type of `qsort`, it only returns `[a]`, not `IO something`, so it can't be used directly inside `main`'s do block.  You could also assign it's returned value to a name using `let`:

```
main = do
    let result = qsort [1, 3, 2]
    print result
```

Comment: i removed the do, then also i get same error. main = qsort [1,2,3]

Comment: @weima If you have `main :: IO ()` and `qsort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]`, you can't say `main = qsort [1, 3, 2]`, because you'd be saying that `main` has type `IO ()` and it has type `[a]`. It'd be like if you had `int x = 1; string y = x;`, most programming languages would reject this as a type mismatch because `string` and `int` aren't the same. That's what is happening here, you've said `main` is one type and then you try to set it equal to a value of another type. You have to convert the output of `qsort` into an `IO` value, and since you want to print it, the `print` function can do this.

Comment: is the type of main fixed? i tried to define main :: [Integer] so that main = qsort[1,2,3] will compile, but it still erros out. seems main must have and IO class output

Comment: Yes, I believe `main` must have the type `IO ()` when your module is called `Main`.  If you haven't specified `module ModuleName where` at the top of your file, then it is implicitly named `Main`.  I believe you can have a `main` function with a different type if the module is not called `Main`, but I'd have to check to make sure that is true.

Comment: The type of `main` must be `IO a`, for some `a` which you choose. If `main` really had type `[Integer]` you could never see the results of your program, because it is impossible to print anything to the screen without doing IO! You'll have to do something like bheklilr suggests, by changing your `main` to first compute the sorted list (of type `[Integer]`), and then print it (resulting in `IO ()`).

Comment: thanks a lot bheklilr and @amalloy for your answer. Helped me a lot to get started with Haskell

Comment: what is the difference between `=` and `<-` ?

Comment: @enzyme With `=`, you are defining a new name exactly equivalent to the expression on the RHS.  The `=` can be used at the top level (not technically true, the top level is actually a `where` clause from the module declaration), or inside a `let` clause.  A `let` clause can only appear as part of an expression, while `where` defines supplementary definitions.  The difference between `map (let f x = x + 1 in f) [1..]` and `map f [1..] where f x = x + 1`.

Comment: @enzyme The `<-` symbol can only be used in a do block, it "extracts" a value from the monadic context and stores that in a name.  It can not be used to define new functions or arbitrary values, but only for getting a value out of a monadic computation within the context of a do block.  The monadic computation must be in the same monad as the containing do block, so if your monad is `IO`, then whenever you use `<-` what's on the RHS of it must have the type `IO something`.