# Compiling / testing Haskell without a main function

Tags: haskell, program-entry-point

I'm working on an assignment in Haskell. However, the base code I am working with does not have a main function defined, and from the wording of the assignment I believe I am not expected to have to write any code outside of the solution to the problem. However, when I try to compile my code, I receive the error:

```
The IO function 'main' is not defined in module 'Main'
```

I assume this is because the function does not have a main function. However, when I try to write my own main function:

```
main :: IO ()
main = solve easy // easy is an array
```

I get the error:

```
Couldn't match expected type 'IO()' with actual type '[Int]'
```

The solve function's type is declared as follows:

```
solve :: [Int] -> [Int]
```

So it takes an array and returns an array. What am I doing wrong in writing my `main` function? Even when I try changing the declaration of `main` to things like:

```
main :: [Int]
```

or

```
main :: IO [Int]
```

I still can't get it to compile.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26474892/102937) for an example of a `main` function in Haskell.  I dispute the notion that your instructor is requiring you to complete the assignment without a `main` function, unless he specifically instructed you as such.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, the print statement solved our problem.

Comment: `easy` is not an array, it is a list. :)

Comment: `main` must be `:: IO t`, and `[Int]` _is most definitely not_ `IO [Int]` Just say `print $` at the start of the declaration. Also, does it need to be compiled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly: the function `main` must have type `IO t` for some type `t`. When the program is executed, the computation defined by `main` is executed, and its result (of type `t`) is thrown away; [see here](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-980005).

So, in particular, you cannot have the type of `main` as `[Int]` and have the compiler not complain.

Depending on whether you want to see the results of solving the easy case or not, you can try one of the following:

If you want to see the results: print them!

```
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ show (solve easy)
```

If you are not interested in seeing the results, throw them away:

```
main :: IO ()
main = let solution = solve easy 
       in putStrLn ""
```

Edit: Note, however, that if you do the latter, then (as @yatima2975 mentions in a comment) the "solve easy" part will *not* be evaluated.

Comment: `putStrLn . show` is the same as `print`, and the second solution only makes sure the types check; that is, `solution` is not evaluated at all!

Comment: @yatima2975 : True. I was not sure of your second point when I wrote the answer, so I did not mention it then. I will add it to the answer now.

Comment: If you want to evaluate the solution but not print it for whatever reason, use `main = Control.Exception.evaluate (solve easy) >> return ()`. Note this only  evaluates to whnf.

Answer (score 8):

Without writing a proper `main` with a correct type, as described by @G Philip, you can load your file in ghci by writing `ghci file.hs` in your terminal, or by invoking `:l file.hs` inside ghci.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to the other answers:

you don't need to write a `main` function and can still compile the file into a lib and the easiest way to do this is just giving a module name (that is not `Main`):

```
module MyCode where

solve :: ...
```

But of course compiling it might not make any sense anymore (as you will not be able to run it - and of course even if you have not specified what to output anyway).

So in this case rather load the file into ghci:

```
ghci MyFile.hs
```

and then everytime you changed something in your code you can do `:r` inside ghci to reload it.

Or even better set up your favorite editor (emacs and vi are quite easy but sublime text and some other works great too) to give you integrated ghci - [this explains](http://www.mew.org/~kazu/proj/ghc-mod/en/preparation.html) what you need to do to setup emacs with haskell-mode if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Consider

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let res = solve easy // easy is an array
    return ()
```

where `return ()` yields a result of type Unit which conveys with the type signature of `main`. Note `solve easy` is bound to `res` which is not used further.